# NSObject extending UIAlertViewDelegate crash?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview

I have a helper class that I want to display a UIAlertView then will perform some web service action. I would like to do it this way so I can re-use the alert view in other places.

I am declaring it like so:

```
@interface FBLinkHelper : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

I also have a method that will show the alert view:

```
- (void) showLinkDialog {
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Link account with Facebook?" message:@"Linking your account with Facebook extends your user experience. Link account?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [av show];
}
```

This is how I am showing the dialog:

```
    FBLinkHelper *fbLinkHelper = [[FBLinkHelper alloc] init];
    [fbLinkHelper showLinkDialog];
```

All seems pretty normal to me. It shows the alert view dialog, but when I click a button (either one) my app crashes without much to say in the console. I notice it *only* crashes when I have a UIAlertViewDelegate method in place, such as didDismissWithButtonIndex. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-UPDATE-

The `FBLinker` instance was not a strong property of its caller, so the delegate callback went to a dangling pointer.  OP reports making `FBLinker` `strong` took care of issue.

Original suggestion of making the class extend from `UIView` instead of `NSObject` had no effect, and is referenced here only for historical purposes.

Comment: Tried it, no luck. Same crash upon tapping either button. I notice it does *not* crash if I don't set a delegate, but obviously that would defeat the purpose here.

Comment: Interesting...is there any sort of stack trace being produced on crash?

Comment: Nothing useful. Crashing in main.m, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: And if you put a breakpoint at the delegate method, does the crash happen before or after the delegate is called?

Comment: Happening before (the breakpoint doesn't fire before the crash). Just tried popping the helper class into a fresh test project and it still crashes, but oddly gives me a somewhat more helpful console log:[__NSMallocBlock__ alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6827e40
2012-06-18 12:48:36.830 AlertTest[8618:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSMallocBlock__ alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6827e40'

Comment: I have a feeling ARC is not retaining the alert view.  Try making the alert view a strong property of the class and instantiating it in the method it is now.

Comment: I had that same thought too. Tried it, still no luck with: @property (nonatomic, strong) UIAlertView *av; This is truly bizarre to me.

Comment: Last idea would be to make your FBLinker instance a strong property of its own caller...

Comment: And for the record, I was able to keep the helper class an NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case in an app I'm working at. If the delegate object isn't a strong (or retain in iOS prior to 5.0) property it might get deallocated right after the UIAlertView is shown.